# Relative Divs but fixed separation distance

Tags: css

I have 3 divs, one big at the top (100%) and 2 after this one (let's say 50%).

I want the distance between the top div and the bottoms divs is the same than the distance that separates the 2 bottoms divs.

Not easy to make clear, see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQshP/

```
.big {
width: 30%;
background-color:olive;
height:50px;
margin-bottom:.5em;
}
.left, .right {
    width:15%;
    height:25px;
    background-color:peru;
    float:left;
}

.left {
    margin-right:.5em;
}
```

While all the divs are relative to its container (% width) I want the separation to be fixed width in px or em.

Comment: i think you have already achieved that

Comment: Surely the distance between top/bottom and left/right is the same - `.5em` in each case?

Comment: But you can see now the last div not right-aligned.

That's because 50%+50%+margin=+100%

I can achieve it if I use % measures for the right margin, but then, it won't be the same than first div bottom margin.

Answer (score 0):

use percentage for margin:

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQshP/1/)

```
.big {
    width: 30%;
    background-color:olive;
    height:50px;
    margin-bottom:2%;
}
.left, .right {
    width:14%;
    height:25px;
    background-color:peru;
    float:left;
}

.left {
    margin-right:2%;
}
```

Comment: That's what I don't want: must be a FIXED distance.